# How to properly run a for loop nth times that has a while read statement and another for loop nested in Bash

Tags: bash, loops, while-loop, scripting

Bash version 4.4.0
Ubuntu 16.04

Initally I have been tring to figure out why when I add the following to my /etc/postfix/main.cf file :

```
#== Sender restrictions:
#== ====================
smtpd_sender_restrictions = reject_unknown_sender_domain, reject_non_fqdn_sender
```

postfix would reject all mail stating that the domain was unknown. So a fella was giving me a hand on stackexchange and asked me to ping the ips that resulted from the servers given by a `nsloohup google.com MX` command. So I wrote a quick script to get the results.

```
#!/bin/bash

  dig google.com MX | sed -n -e '14,18p' | awk '{ print $6 }' | sed 's/.com./.com/g' > .temp

  while read -r fQDN; do
    dig "$fQDN" > "${fQDN}".txt
    nslookup "$fQDN" >> "${fQDN}".txt
  done <.temp

  for file in *.txt; do
    dResults="$(sed '14q;d' "$file" | awk '{ print $5 }')"
    nsResults="$(sed '26q;d' "$file" | awk '{ print $2 }')"
    if [ "$dResults" = "$nsResults" ]; then
      echo "dig + nslookup for ${file::-4} = $dResults"
    else
      echo "dig + nslookup for ${file::-4} don't match!!"
      echo -e "Dig Results:\t $dResults"
      echo -e "Ns Lookup:\t $nsResults"
    fi
    echo ""
  done

  #== Cleanup
  rm -f /home/.work/*.txt /home/.work/.temp
```

So then I wondered if I could loop the entire process a few times as the ping results were mismatched and were not the same each time. So I added a loop like:

```
#!/bin/bash


mkdir -p /home/.work
cd /home/.work || exit 1

for i in 5 4 3 2 1; do
  { clear; echo ""; echo "#== Round $i ..."; echo "#== ============"; }
  sleep 1

  dig google.com MX | sed -n -e '14,18p' | awk '{ print $6 }' | sed 's/.com./.com/g' > .temp

  while read -r fQDN; do
    dig "$fQDN" > "${fQDN}".txt
    nslookup "$fQDN" >> "${fQDN}".txt
  done <.temp

  for file in *.txt; do
    dResults="$(sed '14q;d' "$file" | awk '{ print $5 }')"
    nsResults="$(sed '26q;d' "$file" | awk '{ print $2 }')"
    if [ "$dResults" = "$nsResults" ]; then
      echo "dig + nslookup for ${file::-4} = $dResults"
    else
      echo "dig + nslookup for ${file::-4} don't match!!"
      echo -e "Dig Results:\t $dResults"
      echo -e "Ns Lookup:\t $nsResults"
    fi
    echo ""
  done

  #== Cleanup
  rm -f /home/.work/*.txt /home/.work/.temp

done
```

When I run the script, it only loops the echo statement from the top and runs the remainding of the script once.

[image]

I know I should be more converned about my mail server, which I still am, but I figured I post this to have a better understanding of what I did wrong as I am still a noob in bash scripting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Think about it. If you `sleep 1` right after doing `clear`, then your screen is going to be just empty for 1 second... Then your script will print something. But there is no delay between printing and `clear` - so right after printing it will `clear` and `sleep 1` again with an empty screen.

```
for i in $(seq 5); do
     clear
     echo header
     sleep 1
     # this will be only visible the last time
     echo print something
     # execution flow jump right above to clear
     # so the screen will be cleared right after printing!
done
```

Move the `sleep` statement after you printing is done, so that you have 1 second to actually view it.

```
do_the_work() {
  dig google.com MX | sed -n -e '14,18p' | awk '{ print $6 }' | sed 's/.com./.com/g' > .temp

  while read -r fQDN; do
    dig "$fQDN" > "${fQDN}".txt
    nslookup "$fQDN" >> "${fQDN}".txt
  done <.temp

  for file in *.txt; do
    dResults="$(sed '14q;d' "$file" | awk '{ print $5 }')"
    nsResults="$(sed '26q;d' "$file" | awk '{ print $2 }')"
    if [ "$dResults" = "$nsResults" ]; then
      echo "dig + nslookup for ${file::-4} = $dResults"
    else
      echo "dig + nslookup for ${file::-4} don't match!!"
      echo -e "Dig Results:\t $dResults"
      echo -e "Ns Lookup:\t $nsResults"
    fi
    echo ""
  done

  #== Cleanup
  rm -f /home/.work/*.txt /home/.work/.temp
}
print_header() { 
    echo ""; echo "#== Round $i ..."; echo "#== ============";
}

for i in $(seq 5); do
    clear
    print_header
    do_the_work
    # note - sleep _after_ printing everything and _before_ clearing the screen
    sleep 1
done
```

An advanced script might want to cache the result of computation until it's available, and refresh the screen to minimize flickering. Something along:

```
for i in $(seq 5); do
    start=$(date +%s.%N)

    # nothing to print on the first loop
    if ((i != 1)); then
        clear
        cat <<<"$res"
    fi

    # get and save results
    res=$(print_header; do_the_work)

    if ((i == 1)); then
        # don't wait on first loop
        continue
    fi

    # wait up until a full second since we started
    now=$(date +%s.%N)
    if ! awk '{exit $2 >= $1}' <<<"$start $now"; then
       # wait up until one second since we started
       still_to_wait=$(awk '{print $2 - $1}' <<<"$start $now")
       sleep "$still_to_wait"
    else
       : # execution took longer then a second, just continue
    fi

done
```

You could also use `watch` with `timeout`.

Comment: The obvious escapes me sometimes. I surely appeciate the answer and your time. Hats off to you mate!